# Get deepAR fit() metrics to python

Tags: python, rnn, aws

I use deepAR RNN on AWS via python. I run the `estimator.fit(inputs=data_channels)` and want to get insight on the algorithm performance and the fit that the model obtained, i.e. epoch to epoch convergence, quantile loss, RMSE, etc..

Instead I get a log dump like this:

```
 [05/10/2018 09:44:02 INFO 140424081053504] #test_score (algo-1, wQuantileLoss[0.5]): 0.0768988
[05/10/2018 09:44:02 INFO 140424081053504] #test_score (algo-1, wQuantileLoss[0.9]): 0.037788
[05/10/2018 09:44:02 INFO 140424081053504] #test_score (algo-1, RMSE): 4433.98308522
#metrics {"Metrics": {"totaltime": {"count": 1, "max": 125569.84615325928, "sum": 125569.84615325928, "min": 125569.84615325928}, "setuptime": {"count": 1, "max": 14.33110237121582, "sum": 14.33110237121582, "min": 14.33110237121582}}, "EndTime": 1525945442.991945, "Dimensions": {"Host": "algo-1", "Operation": "training", "Algorithm": "AWS/DeepAR"}, "StartTime": 1525945442.891469}
```

which is completely unreadable and unprocessable.

Is there a way to get those metrics back to python?

PS. The folder in `output_path` of estimator contains some files, but they do not seem to have the results I am looking for

I managed to handle this way, yet horribly inefficient:

1. First I capture the console output with this trick:

   f = io.StringIO()
   with redirect_stdout(f):
       estimator.fit(inputs=data_channels)
   dr_log = f.getvalue()
2. Then I manually process the long multiline string (blaaah:/)

   def dr_metrics(log, r):
   rr = list()
   final_res = dict()
   for line in log:
       if "Epoch" in line:
           l = line.split("]")
           print(l)

   ```
       e = l[-3].split("[")[-1]
       b = l[-2].split("[")[-1]
       val = l[-1][:-2].split("=")[1]
       rr.append([e, b, val, "Speed" in line])
       print([e, b, val])
   if "Final loss" in line:
       final_res['final_loss'] = line.split(":")[-1].split(" ")[1]
   if "#quality_metric" in line:
       if "mean_wQuantileLoss" in line:
           final_res['mean_wQuantileLoss'] = line.split("=")[-1]
       if "RMSE" in line:
           final_res['RMSE'] = line.split("=")[-1]
   ```

   res_df = pd.DataFrame(rr, columns=["Epoch", "Batch", "AvgLoss", "EpochEnd"])
   res_df.head(10)
   print(final_res)

Comment: I found this way around, but still needs some processing     f = `io.StringIO()
    with redirect_stdout(f):
        estimator.fit(inputs=data_channels)
    print(f.getvalue())`